# Remove all tags <a> with Notepad + +

Tags: regex, notepad++

I want to remove from the text of all links (`<a href=""></a>`), except for those who have  tag attribute `href="site.com"` (for example).

```
<a href="site.com">text</a>
<a href="google.com">text</a>
<a href="yandex.com">text</a>
```

That is that the last two links left. Can you please tell the correct regular expression for it (in Notepad + +).

Comment: Show what you have tried please.

Comment: what should the result for the given example be. please edit your question to show the exact result.

Comment: I only know `<a href=".*">.*</a>` to remove all links, and I need to remove all the links, except for those who href="site.com". How to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, the `.*` should be lazy, because otherwise, you will be matching more than necessary.

```
<a href=".*?">.*?</a>
```

Next, you can make use of a negative lookahead to prevent matches from `<a href="site.com">text</a>` and you do it like this:

```
<a href="(?!site.com">).*?">.*?</a>
```

Result if you replace by nothing will be that only `<a href="site.com">text</a>` will be left.

If you want to keep the text, wrap the text around parentheses and call it in the replace:

```
<a href="(?!site.com">).*?">(.*?)</a>
```

And replace with `$1`.

Be sure to select "Regular expression". And if your links span multiples lines, check the checkboxbox ". matches newline" as well.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but I do not work! Do not look for links on this regular expression!

Comment: @ДокторСкальпинг Did you check the regular expression checkbox? http://i.stack.imgur.com/YTTyu.png

Comment: Sure, but what is your version of Notepad++?

Comment: Updated Notepad++ and your regular expression worked. Thank you!

Comment: @ДокторСкальпинг Oh, it was a version issue ^^; Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 1):

None of these seem to work if I want to remove all hyperlinks but keep the text. The example does not even find any link at all.

```
 <a(.*?)>(.*)</a>
```

The following correctly finds the link

```
<a .*?.*?</a>
```

But if I use $1 or $2 it simply deletes the link & anchor text

I want to keep the text

My Solution:

```
<a .*?.*?>
```

This will delete the opening tag of the link leaving the text & remaining tag - then you can just delete the `</a>`

Answer (score 0):

A very easy and generic solution could be:

```
Find: <a(.*?)>(.*)</a>
Replace: $2
```

$2 will leave the text of HyperLink.